# What do you call the automatic bike pedals in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, sports

I mean those kind of bicycle pedals where you have special shoes and engage the sole to the pedal. In Spanish it's *pedales automaticos* and in German: 'Klickis' or 'Klickpedale'.

Comment: The word that comes to mind is "clip pedals", but the fun is that since the 90's there are "clipless" pedals, which attach to your shoes without the traditional clips.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i was looking for. 'clipless' is actually confusing from my point of view, but a quick search on the internet showed that it is the word what I was looking for. Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: Yes, it confuses everyone. I like klickis better :-)

Comment: BTW Stack Exchange also has a [Cycling](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Another option is "step-in pedals": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_pedal#Clipless_pedals - clipless is confusing but comes from contrast with the older "toeclips" system like a cage around the front of the shoe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word that comes to mind is "clip pedals".

The funny - and confusing part is that since the 90's there are "clipless" pedals, which attach to your shoes without the traditional clips - they still attach to your shoes in a different way, though.

So I guess *both* clip pedals and clipless pedals would describe the word you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

"Toe clips" is the word, although there seems to be a variant. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toe_clips#Types

Comment: I don't think toe clips are what OP is asking for - you insert your foot into the toe clip, while the "klickis" are something that you step on (they attach the bottom of the foot to the pedal with a "click").